# alpine/git clone not working on windows with docker

Tags: git, docker

I've recently switched to a windows machine from a Mac and wanted to test out a couple of things, mainly with Docker. Normally, I don't have to install anything on my Mac and it just works as long as I have Docker installed.

With Windows, I downloaded Docker and got it to work. When trying out commands, it seems like it does something but ultimately nothing happens.

For example, I download Cygwin Terminal since none of the other terminals could recognize basic commands.

I then pulled in the alpine/git package and ran the following command:

```
$ docker run -ti --rm -v ${HOME}:/root -v $(pwd):/git alpine/git clone 
https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git
Cloning into 'Hello-World'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 13, done.
remote: Total 13 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 13
Receiving objects: 100% (13/13), done.
```

But I have no idea where that went. I know that `${HOME}` and `$(pwd)` print `/home/dinoc` and I know that's in the `C:\cygwin64\home\dinoc` directory, but it's not there.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm *guessing* there's a conflict between the environment variables that the docker service can see, and the environment variables that you see. On Windows the docker daemon runs as a Windows Service and that can't see any of the cygwin enviornmental variables.  I'd check `C:\Users\dinoc` (Use Windows explorer, or in cygwin bash I *think* it's `/cygdrive/c/Users/dinoc` )

Comment: FWIW you may find it worth investigating Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2) - that lets you run up a proper Linux install which is a lot closer to a Mac than Windows + Cygwin.  I use docker under WSL2 on my Windows machine.  Need a fairly recent version of Windows though.

Comment: Thanks that did it! I just installed Ubuntu and viola, everything is right again. Appreciate the help!